# Adding fields to model which derived from Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a Mongoose schema that looks like this:

```
ManifestSchema = new Schema({
entries: [{
            order_id: String,
            line_item: {}, // <-- resolved at run time
            address: {},// <-- resolved at run time
            added_at: Number,
            stop: Number,

        }]

}, {collection: 'manifests', strict: true });
```

and somewhere in the code I have this:

```
Q.ninvoke(Manifests.findById(req.params.id), 'exec')
.then(function(manifest)
{
// ... so many things, like resolving the address and the item information
entry.line_item = item;
entry.address = order.delivery.address;
})
```

The issue that I faced is that without defining address and line_item in the schema, when I resolved them at run time, they wouldn't returned to the user because they weren't in the schema...so I added them...which cause me another unwanted behavior: When I saved the object back, both address and line_item were saved with the manifest object, something that I would like to avoid.

Is there anyway to enable adding fields to the schema at run time, but yet, not saving them on the way back?

I was trying to use 'virtuals' in mongoose, but they really provide what I need because I don't create the model from a schema, but it rather returned from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on your `manifest` Mongoose instance to create a plain JavaScript copy that you can add extra fields to for the user response without affecting the doc you need to save:

```
Q.ninvoke(Manifests.findById(req.params.id), 'exec')
.then(function(manifest)
{
  var manifestResponse = manifest.toObject();

  // ... so many things, like resolving the address and the item information
  entry.line_item = item;
  entry.address = order.delivery.address;
})
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Do you know the details of why this works? What makes the entity returned from mongoose different from a 'plain javascript' object?

Comment: @DanielFlippance One key difference is that the properties of Mongoose docs are defined using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).